# Why does LINQ to SQL translate GroupBy into multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I've noticed than even my simpler LINQ queries using GroupBy get translated into as many SQL queries as group keys. I haven't found any explanation as to why this happens or how I can avoid it.

For instance, the query:

```
from p in People group p by p.Name into g select g
```

gets translated into as many `selects` as different values for the column `Name`, just like this one:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 VarChar(20) SET @x1 = 'John'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Name], [t0].[SurName]
FROM [People] AS [t0]
WHERE ((@x1 IS NULL) AND ([t0].[Name] IS NULL)) 
     OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[Name] IS NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = [t0].[Name]))
GO
```

However, if I bring the whole table to memory, such as calling `AsEnumerable()`,

```
from p in People.AsEnumerable() group p by p.Name into g select g
```

just a single select is issued, retrieving all the rows and then LINQ performs the grouping in memory.

I find this behavior rather confusing and error-prone since I often find myself composing complex queries in different statements and I must be careful enough to call `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` before performing a `GroupBy` or my performance gets degraded. Even worse, it forces me to finish my `LINQ to SQL` query and continue with `LINQ to Objects`.

I've tested this both using `LINQ to Entities` and `LINQ to SQL` (through `LINQPad`), the DBMS being  `SQL Server`.

Am I missing something? Is this by design or is there any way to write the LINQ query in such a way that SQL's `GROUP BY` is used instead of multiple individual queries being generated?

Comment: SQL's group by and LINQ's group by do vastly different things.  There is no 1-1 mapping between them.  If you wrote a `GroupBy` LINQ query *that could actually be translated into a SQL group by*, then it may well do so.

Comment: @Servy thanks. Yeah, obviously that's the case for most LINQ to SQL translations but, how is this decided? I guess it must be deterministic, how come the apparently most simple LINQ `GroupBy` query ends up not using SQL `group by`?

Comment: There is a query translator who's job it is to translate the code from the expression tree into SQL.  Sometimes it can do it well, sometimes it can do it, but not as well as you'd like, and sometimes it just can't.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your select statement so it is more SQL friendly.

change: `select g`

to something like this:

```
select new
{
  g.Key,
  Count = g.Count(),
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that query gets easily translated into SQL `group by` because it only involves an aggregate function and the aggregate column, but what happens when we also need to retrieve the items in the group? 
Is there a way to write the LINQ query so that a single SQL query is generated - or at least increase the chances?

Comment: @jnovo - The `GROUP BY` clause is used to project rows having common values into a smaller set of rows. `GROUP BY` is often used in conjunction with `SQL` aggregation functions or to eliminate duplicate rows from a result set. 
If you want all the rows than there is nothing wrong with using `People.AsEnumerable()`