# Does LINQ try to solve things in one pass?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Say we have `list.Where(p=>p.Number > n).Select(p=> p.Name).Where(n=> n.StartsWith(a)).ToList();` will this be ran one pass algorithm or it will be 3 passes?

Comment: Say we have a state exam and students are asked to solve a simple algorithmic task that can be solved via C# LINQ in one nice, simple query. Yet if they can not prove in runs in one pass it will be considered unoptimal solution and students will get bad grades.

Comment: Note that there is a similar question re Linq2SQL: will the resulting query be performed using a single `SELECT` statement? For simple queries like your example, if they can be converted to an SQL query the answer is, yes. But some [complex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22816591/256431) [queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264751/256431) do not do this, and I don't know if any guarantee is given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will build up the list in one pass, due to the way that LINQ *streams* the data.

For example, take this:

```
var query = list.Where(p => p.Number > n);
```

That in itself doesn't look at *any* of the elements of the list. Instead, it remembers the list you're looking at, and when you start iterating over `query`, each time you ask for the next element, it will check the elements of the list in turn until it finds a match - then stop. For example:

```
using (var iterator = query.GetEnumerator())
{
    iterator.MoveNext(); // This will look for the first match
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current);

    iterator.MoveNext(); // This will continue from just after the first match
}
```

Each of the operations works that way - so by the time you've got:

```
var query = list.Where(...)
                .Select(...)
                .Where(...);
```

... when you ask for the first item within `query`, it will chain back up (so the last `Where` will ask the result of `Select`, which will ask the result of the first `Where`, which will ask the list) and keep going until it's got a result. Then when you ask for the next item, that will ask the result of `Select` for the next item, etc.

`ToList` builds up a `List<T>` from all the items in its source, immediately - it's *eager* in that sense (rather than the other operators here which are *lazy*). But the original list itself will still only be iterated over once.

For a *lot* more detail on how LINQ to Objects works - including a sample implementation - you might want to read my [Edulinq blog series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).

Answer (score 8):

`list` would only be iterated once in that code, not 3 times.

Of course, if you want to test if any arbitrary query iterates the source multiple times it's easy enough to test experimentally, just create an `IEnumerable` that throws an exception when you attempt to iterate it multiple times:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ThereCanBeOnlyOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new SingleEnumerable<T>(source);
}

private class SingleEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private bool hasRun = false;
    private IEnumerable<T> wrapped;
    public SingleEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> wrapped)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (hasRun)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Sequence cannot be enumerated multilpe times");
        else
        {
            hasRun = true;
            return wrapped.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can just write:

```
list.ThereCanBeOnlyOne()
    .Where(p=>p.Number > n)
    .Select(p=> p.Name)
    .Where(n=> n.StartsWith(a))
    .ToList();
```

If the code throws an exception, you tried to iterate the underlying list multiple times.  If not, you didn't.